# "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: git, shell, command-line, blob, command-line-arguments

I am running 
`for blob in $(git fsck --lost-found | awk ‘$2 == “blob” { print $3 }’); do git cat-file -p $blob > $blob.txt; done`
and getting a "blob was unexpected at this time". How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Fix your quotes. It should be `"blob"`, not `“blob”`. The first one is valid code, the second one is decorative typography.